# how to pass optional parameter in swagger php api annotation?

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-php

> I am using swagger ui and i have a Get api which take take optional
>   parameter but i am unable to give annotation for that api below is
>   make code which i have tried:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Get(
 *     path="/basics/checkDataNameAvailability/{type}/{name}{/id}",
 *     tags={"Emergency"},
 *     description="Return data useful for userGroup, deviceGroups and deviceTags",
 *     produces={"application/json", "application/xml", "text/xml", "text/html"},
 *     @SWG\Parameter(name="type",in="path",description="return useful data by type",required=true,type="integer", @SWG\Items(type="integer"),collectionFormat="csv",format="int32"),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(name="name",in="path",description="return useful data by name",required=true,type="integer", @SWG\Items(type="integer"),collectionFormat="csv",format="int32"),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(name="id",in="path",description="optional, useful data by id",required=true,type="integer", @SWG\Items(type="integer"),collectionFormat="csv",format="int32"),
 *     @SWG\Response(response=200,description="Dashboard Response",
 *          @SWG\Schema(type="array",@SWG\Items(ref="#/definitions/Pet"))
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Response(response="default",description="unexpected error",
 *          @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/ErrorModel")
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\ExternalDocumentation(description="find more info here", url="https://swagger.io/about")
 * )
 */
```

and my Get api structure is like:

```
$app->get('/checkDataNameAvailability/:type/:name(/:id)', function($type, $name, $id = '') use($app){
//here is my api code
});
```

But when i am trying this so swagger ui does not take **id** optional parameter, it take required parameter, help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define an *optional* parameter, you just need to not define it as *NOT required*.

The `id` parameter has `required=true`:

```
@SWG\Parameter(name="id",in="path",description="optional, useful data by id",required=true,type="integer", @SWG\Items(type="integer"),collectionFormat="csv",format="int32")
```

You just need to set it to false:

```
@SWG\Parameter(name="id",in="path",description="optional, useful data by id",required=false,type="integer", @SWG\Items(type="integer"),collectionFormat="csv",format="int32")
```

Removing `required=true`also make this parameter optional

```
@SWG\Parameter(name="id",in="path",description="optional, useful data by id",type="integer", @SWG\Items(type="integer"),collectionFormat="csv",format="int32")
```

Comment: `@SWG` is now deprecated, also the docs now, sadly, say "Also remember to add required: true, because path parameters are always required." https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/ You know have to define 2 paths, or use query parameters (after `?`)